# Locale specific BigDecimal formatting in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I've tried coming up with a solution to this problem by combining a few separate issues other people posted on this site, but somehow can't get it right.

I receive a BigDecimal from the server which I need to display in a TextBox inside a GWT page.

```
BigDecimal bigDec = new BigDecimal(type.mb3.toString()).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
t12.setText(bigDec.toString());
```

After this call the TextBox displays ex. `1200.00`, which is the correct value, however I would like for it to be formatted with a German locale `##0,00`.

I can't convert it by specifying the format via NumberFormat, as it doesn't accept BigDecimal. Is there another way I can format this without writing a neanderthal "if you see dot exchange it for comma" text parser?

Comment: `NumberFormat` is supposed to support formatting `BigDecimal` (as a `java.lang.Number`). Does it not work for you?

Comment: Oh my god I spent hours researching and somehow I missed/didn't think to use Number :/ Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment Thomas Broyer provided was the answer. I needed to use `java.lang.Number` instead of pure BigDecimal and it formatted correctly.